How to convolute with a Heaviside step function?
I have the following convolution integral between $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $g(x) = \Theta(a-x)$:
$$I = \int \frac{\theta(a-x)}{x^2}dx \ \ \ \ 0\le x < \infty, a>0$$
The result according to Wolframalpha is:
$$I = - \Bigg(\Big(\frac{1}{x}+C\Big)\Theta(a-x) + \Big(\frac{1}{a}+D\Big)\Theta(x-a) \Bigg)$$
Writing the Heaviside step as a piecewise function:
$$\Theta(a-x) = \cases{1 & $x\le a$ \\ 0 & $x>a$}$$
Convoluting this with $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$:
$$I = \int \cases{1\cdot\frac{1}{x^2} & $x\le a$ \\ 0\cdot\frac{1}{x^2} & $x>a$} dx = \cases{-\frac{1}{x}+C & $x\le a$\\ D & x>a} = \Big(-\frac{1}{x}+C\Big)\Theta(a-x) + D\Theta(x-a)$$
It looks like for the second piece where $x>a$, I'm supposed to get $F(a)+D$ from integrating $0$. How?

@TrevorNorton yes, I am performing an indefinite integral

That should not change anything since $F(a)$ is just a constant, right? In any case, that is not how you integrate a piecewise defined function. Try to write the indefinite integral as a definite one from $+\infty$ to $x$ and you will see that when $x<a$ you have to split the integral in two pieces, and you will get that $-1/a$. You then add the arbitrary constant at the end to get the indefinite integral.

$$\int_{\infty}^x \frac{\Theta(a-x')}{x'^2}dx'  \ = \int_{\infty}^x \cases{\frac{1}{x'^2} & $x'<a$ \ 0 & $x'>a$} \= \int_{\infty}^a 0 dx' + \int_a^x \frac{1}{x'^2}dx' \ = \frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{x}$$ which I verified the result of here as well. We're missing Heaviside step function, and our sign is off for our $\frac{1}{a}$ term. Did I set up my integral incorrectly? You said we wanted 2 pieces for our integral over $x<a$?

@LorenzoPompili Forgot to tag you in my last comment. I put together the integral and evaluated it, but not sure what went wrong.

Looks correct to me. If you integrate from $+\infty$ to $x$, you get $0$ if $x>a$, and $1/a-1/x$ if $x<a$. If you add the $+C$ for the indefinite integral, you get $I=\theta(a-x)(1/a-1/x)+0\cdot \theta(x-a)+C$. By redefining $C$, you can write it as $I=-\frac 1x \theta(a-x)-\frac 1a \theta(x-a)+C$. Both are correct solutions. The solution of Wolfram is almost correct: you don't have two arbitrary contants $C$ and $D$, you just have one constant $C$.
